# How do I set an initializer for a custom UITableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, initialization, init

I've searched around for an answer to this, but each solution just brings new compiler errors.

**How do I set up the initializers for a class that inherits from UITableViewCell?**

This is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated:

**SettingCell.swift**

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var settingsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingsSwitch: UISwitch?
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSetting: UILabel?

    var cellDelegate: SettingCellDelegate?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    init(settingLabel: UILabel!, settingSwitch: UISwitch?, timeSetting: UILabel?) {

        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
        self.settingsLabel = settingLabel
        self.settingsSwitch = settingSwitch
        self.timeSetting = timeSetting

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @IBAction func handledSwitchChange(sender: UISwitch) {

        self.cellDelegate?.didChangeSwitchState(sender: self, isOn:settingsSwitch!.on)


    }
   ...

}
```

**Fix-It Error:**

[image]

**Compiler Error:**

```
'UITableViewCellStyle.Type' is not convertible to 'UITableViewCellStyle'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call this line:

```
super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

you need to supply an actual cell style and an actual reuse identifier. You code at the moment is written as if this line is a function definition, not a function invocation.

Change it to something like:

```
super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "SettingCell")
```

(though preferably at least the reuse identifier should be provided by the caller, not statically)

Comment: thanks for the response wain, here's the error that the compiler returns when I use your signature: 'UITableViewCellStyle.Type' does not have a member named 'UITableViewCellStyleDefault'

Comment: ok, got it just changed it to: super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "SettingCell")

Comment: Sorry, that was the obj-c version of the enum